# How to scrape to get say tags(<p> </p>) all in the scraped data as maintained in the html structure say

Tags: php, web-scraping

```html
<html>my news article</html>
<title>scraping</title>
<p>the world of so many articles</p>
<p>has been placed in this blocknotes</p>
<p>and i really wanna scraped that html structure just as it is</p>
<p>with all the tags in the scraped data</p>
```

How to **scrape** with all tags in it?

I want the scraped data to be like...........

Comment: Do you want to get the texts inside every `<p>` tag?

Comment: I mean, what do you want to achieve? Maybe post a sample output?

Comment: i want the scraped data to be like..................<p>the world of so many articles</p>
<p>has been placed in this blocknotes</p>
<p>and i really wanna scraped that html structure just as it is</p>
<p>with all the tags in the scrapped data</p>

Comment: But the results? All the `<p>` tags together in a string? Each `<p>` tag in a different item inside a list?

Comment: i want all the tags in it so that i can work with it by getting the maintained structure of the article on the site.

Answer (score 1):

**This Python script may help:**

```
from lxml import html

HTML = """<html>
<title>scraping</title>
<p>the world of so many articles</p>
<p>has been placed in this blocknotes</p>
<p>and i really wanna scraped that html structure just as it is</p>
<p>with all the tags in the scrapped data</p>
</html>"""

tree = html.fromstring(HTML)
print ' '.join("<p>{}</p>".format(x) for x in tree.xpath('//p/text()'))
```

**Output:**

```
<p>the world of so many articles</p> <p>has been placed in this blocknotes</p> <p>and i really wanna scraped that html structure just as it is</p> <p>with all the tags in the scrapped data</p>
```

Comment: Please I am using PHP Curl and DomXpath not Python